# GHC package conflicts

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, package, ghc

I'm trying to compile the following code with GHC:

```
module Test where

import Maybe
import Prelude hiding (null)
import System.IO

null = ()

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"
```

If I just run `ghc Test.hs`, I get:

```
Could not find module `Maybe'
It is a member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.1'.
```

So I try `ghc -package haskell98 Test.hs`:

```
Ambiguous module name `Prelude':
  it was found in multiple packages: base haskell98-2.0.0.1
```

It doesn't seem right, but I try `ghc -package haskell98 -hide-package base Test.hs`:

```
Could not find module `System.IO'
It is a member of the hidden package `base'.
It is a member of the hidden package `haskell2010-1.1.0.1'.
```

So then I try `ghc -package haskell98 -hide-package base -package haskell2010 Test.hs`:

```
Ambiguous module name `Prelude':
  it was found in multiple packages:
  haskell2010-1.1.0.1 haskell98-2.0.0.1
```

How do I compile this code?  I'm using GHC 7.4.1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Import `Data.Maybe`. The `haskell98` package is no longer compatible with `base`, so using the `haskell98` modules brings just unnecessary pain.

Comment: I thought that Maybe and Data.Maybe were distinct modules.  Are they equivalent?

Comment: @AdamCrume: [Data.Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html) is pretty much a superset of the old [Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/haskell98/Maybe.html) module. If you compare the docs, you can see that the main difference is that Data.Maybe exports more instances.

Comment: `Mabye` is just the haskell98 wrapper around `Data.Maybe`. They are equivalent in almost all respects except that using `Maybe` requires you to jump through a number of hoops now since you can't use it together with base.

Answer (score 12):

The idea is that you use exactly one of `haskell98`, `base`, or `haskell2010`. The `haskell*` packages are the set of libraries mandated by the corresponding language standard, so if you use one of those you have a better chance of being compatible with non-GHC compilers. However, the vast majority of packages on Hackage use `base` anyway, so you're probably better off sticking with that.

Haskell98 strictly speaking predates hierarchical modules, so that's why they are all called `Maybe` and `List` and `IO` and so forth. (Actually, I think these are better names than what they are now, but that's another story). Your problem is that you were trying to use the old `Maybe` and the new `System.IO` at the same time, and neither the old nor the new package provides both.