# Haskell IO hidden file or prelude ambiguous

Tags: haskell

I have recently downloaded ghci, however when i try to compile my .hs file it says that IO module is in the hidden package haskell98-2.0.0.1. When i expose it using `ghc-pkg expose haskell98-2.0.0.1`, it then had a problem with base and prelude saying that prelude is ambiguous.

How can i get around this so i can compile my program correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your .hs file and what's version of ghc/ghci?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10480677/812053 . Not sure if this is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ghc, you should use System.IO module, that is part of `base` package. Haskel-98 is... well, out of fashion now. If you want to stick with haskell-98 (this will make impossible to work with most existing libraries), you should expose `haskell98` and hide `base`, as both `base` and `haskell98` contain `Prelude` module, so compiler cannot guess which one to import, and it has to import Prelude some way because of standard.

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do here (as permeakra pointed out), would be to use the `System.IO` module, which is done by placing

```
import System.IO
```

near the top of your file (under the module declaration (if you have one) but on top of everything else).