# In Haskell,failed to loaded with an error message " Could not find module `IO' "

Tags: haskell

I use WinGHCi and my Code(really simple) follows:

```
module Main 
    where

import IO

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
  putStrLn "Enter your name: "
  name <- getLine
  putStrLn("Hello, " ++ name ++ ", how are you?");
```

error message:

```
2.hs:4:8:
    Could not find module `IO'
    It is a member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.1'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

(That codes run correctly in WinHugs, but I just want to compile it)

Maybe the question is really trivial, but I'm study Haskell by myself and nobody can be consulted. I try to search in Google, unfortunately can't find anything meaningful.

I get stuck...Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10480677/812053) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to import `System.IO`.

Comment: Wow, simple but works! That's a sample code on a book, and I just know little about Haskell ... Really thanks!

Comment: @Sayakiss: the `IO` module is part of the Haskell98 standard, and the community has moved on.  When looking at older references you may want to check the Haskell2010 standard to see the new names; it's usually obvious how the old modules fit into the hierarchy: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/

Comment: I came across the same problem. The code is from [Yet Another Haskell Tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/YAHT).